# Java - Не правильный подсчёт размера строки из загружаемого файла на русском языке

Tags: java

Моя задача такова: из .txt файла сначала загружается только первая строка - по её размеру определяется центрирование текста.

Проблема: если запускать программу из IDE(Ecplise) то всё хорошо. Если скомпилировать в .jar, и запустить вне среды разработки, то размер строки начинает считаться неверно. Проблема именно с русскими символами - на англ. такого нету. Пробовал разные кодировки, делу не помогло.

Вот функция по которой я рисую текст:
1. Загружаю первую строку
2. Загружаю весь текст
3. Вывожу всё

```
    public void drawText(Graphics g, String textFile) {

    int y = 110;

    String text = "", firstLine = ""; 

    FileReader fr;

    try {

        fr = new FileReader(textFile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        firstLine = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(textFile)), "MS932");
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(text) + " - " + g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(firstLine), 32, 160);

    y += textScroll;

    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    for (String line : text.split("\n"))
        g.drawString(line, getWidth() / 2 - g.getFontMetrics(gameFont).stringWidth(firstLine) / 2, y +=  g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
}
```

Значит вообщем - вот это:

```
g.getFontMetrics(gameFont).stringWidth(firstLine)
```

перестаёт правильно работать если именно загружать, именно русский текст из файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо этого:

```
fr = new FileReader(textFile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Напишите это:

```
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

И в настройках IDE должно быть UTF_8.

Если используете IntelliJ IDEA, то Setting -> Editor -> File Encodings

Comment: Воу, это и правда помогло. Я уже 3 день с этим бьюсь - хотел об клавиатуру самоубиться. На самом деле не додумался бы сам до такого. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Не за что. Рада что смогла помочь. Я три дня назад с этим билась также как и вы))) Хорошо добрые люди подсказали)